# Is there a JMESPath equivalent to XPath double slash (//) "any descendant" search?

Tags: xpath, jmespath

In XPath, to search for any descendants that match a certain path, say, `a` elements at any level with a `b` element as a child, one would use the query `//a/b`.

E.g., for the following document

```xml
<foo>
  <bar>
    <a><b>first</b></a>
  </bar>
  <a><b>second</b></a>
</foo>
```

using the aforementioned xpath, we would find the elements `<b>first</b>` and `<b>second</b>`.

Is there an equivalent for JSON and JMESPath?

E.g.:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "a": {"b": "first"}
    },
    "a": {"b": "second"}
  }
}
```

From the above document, is it possible to retrieve `{"b": "first"}` and `{"b": "second"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The below query

```
foo.a
```

gives

```yaml
{
  "b": "second"
}
```

and

```
foo.*.a | [0]
```

gives

```yaml
{
  "b": "first"
}
```